# Error: The type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' has no constructors defined

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to change password option with ms access database....

please help me folks....

here the code: 
default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vhgroupconnection"].ConnectionString);
        myCon.Open();

        string userid = txtuserid.Text;
        string oldpass = txtoldpass.Text;
        string newPass = txtnewpass.Text;
        string conPass = txtconfirmpass.Text;

        string q = "select user_id,passwd from register where user_id = @userid and       passwd = @oldpass";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, myCon);

        OleDbDataReader reader = new OleDbDataReader();



        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", txtuserid.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldpass", txtoldpass.Text);



        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();

        if (reader["user_id"].ToString() != String.Empty && reader["passwd"].ToString() != String.Empty)
        {
            if (newPass.Trim() != conPass.Trim())
            {
                lblmsg.Text = "New Password and old password does not match";

            }
            else
            {
                q = "UPDATE register SET passwd = @newPass WHERE user_id =@userid";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, myCon);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newPasss", txtnewpass.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userod", txtuserid.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwd", txtoldpass.Text);

                int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (count > 0)
                {
                    lblmsg.Text = "Password changed successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblmsg.Text = "password not changed";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

also check pls.....

> Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0143: The type
>   'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' has no constructors defined

Source Error:

```
Line 36:             OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, myCon);
Line 37: 
Line 38:             OleDbDataReader reader = new OleDbDataReader();
Line 39:             
Line 40:
```

Answer (score 1):

As error message says; [`OleDbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has no constructor.

From [documentation of `OleDbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> To create an `OleDbDataReader`, you must call the `ExecuteReader` method
>   of the `OleDbCommand` object, instead of directly using a constructor.

You can use [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344900%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that returns `OleDbDataReader`

```
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

And you need add your parameter values **before** you call `ExecuteReader` method.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection`, `OleDbCommand` and `OleDbDataReader` like;

```
using(OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = myCon.CreateCommand())
{
    //Define your sql query and add your parameter values.

    using(OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       //
    }  
}
```

And as Steve [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648081/error-the-type-system-data-oledb-oledbdatareader-has-no-constructors-defined/24648139?noredirect=1#comment38206849_24648139), [`OleDbDataReader.Read` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `boolean` value (`true` of `false`) and it reads your `OleDbDataReader` results *row by row*. You might need to consider to use the result of this method like in a *while statement*. For example;

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    //Reads your results until the last row..
}
```

As a final words, I strongly suspect you store your passwords as plain text. **Don't do that!** Use [SHA-512 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

Comment: +1 but there is also a very wrong second part of that code with no check on the result of reader.Read()

Answer (score 0):

As MSDN clearly states, `To create an OleDbDataReader, you must call the ExecuteReader method of the OleDbCommand object, instead of directly using a constructor.`

You cannot instantiate it using `new`, which is what you are doing and which is why you get the error. Remove the offending line and change it to this to get rid of the error:

```
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Also, remember to use `using` blocks to ensure resources get properly disposed.

```
using(OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vhgroupconnection"].ConnectionString))
{
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, myCon);

 //Add parameters etc

OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

//Rest of the processing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**: You try to make new instance of `OleDbDataReader` by calling `new OleDbDataReader()` instead you should create a reader using `OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()`.

In the following code notice use of `using` statement (this should ensure connection closing or reader closing for the case of `OleDbDataReader`).

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string sConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vhgroupconnection"].ConnectionString;
        using(OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(sConnString))
        {
             myCon.Open();
             string userid = txtuserid.Text;
             string oldpass = txtoldpass.Text;
             string newPass = txtnewpass.Text;
             string conPass = txtconfirmpass.Text;

             string q = "select user_id,passwd from register where user_id = @userid and passwd = @oldpass";

             OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, myCon);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", txtuserid.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldpass", txtoldpass.Text);

             string sUserId = string.Empty;
             string sPass = string.Empty;

             using(OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
             {
                if(reader.Read()) //assumption: one record returned
                {           
                   sUserId = reader["user_id"].ToString();
                   sPass = reader["passwd"].ToString();

                }
             }

             if (sUserId != string.Empty && sPass != string.Empty)
             {
               if (newPass.Trim() != conPass.Trim())                   
                   lblmsg.Text = "New Password and old password does not match";
               else
               {
                    q = "UPDATE register SET passwd = @newPass WHERE user_id =@userid";
                    cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, myCon);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newPass", txtnewpass.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", txtuserid.Text);                       

                    int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (count > 0)                
                       lblmsg.Text = "Password changed successfully";                
                    else                
                       lblmsg.Text = "password not changed";

               }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw ex;
      }
}
```

Comment: thanks folk... but again i get the error as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:


Line 76:         catch (Exception ex)
Line 77:         {
Line 78:             throw ex;
Line 79:         }
Line 80:     }

Comment: I have modified answer. Can you check now?